# C++ macros and namespaces

Tags: c++, macros, namespaces

I've got a problem with using macros in namespaces.
The code is

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a
{
#define MESSAGE_A(message) \
    std::cout << (message) << std::endl;
}

#define MESSAGE_A(message) \
    std::cout << (message) << std::endl;

int main()
{
    //works fine
    MESSAGE_A("Test");
    //invalid
    a::MESSAGE_A("Test")
    return 0;
}
```

What's the proper variant of using namespaced objects in macros.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Macros are handled by the pre-processor, which knows nothing about namespaces.
So macros aren't namespaced, they are just text substitution. The use of macros really is discouraged, among other reasons because they always pollute the global namespace.

If you need to print out a message, and you need it to be namespaced, simply use an inline function. The code seems simple enough to be properly inlined:

```
namespace a
{
  inline void MESSAGE_A(const char* message) 
  {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It will not work. Macroses knows nothing about namespaces. If you want to use namespaces - you must not use macroses.

Comment: Could help with a workaround solution. In my project I have to use macros in namespace and they have to call macros from another namespace.

Comment: @MaxFX, macros aren't "called", they are substituted. If you need to use macros for something overly complex, you are doing something wrong.